# Clearing/resetting displayed values. Clearing answer variables in Javascript/HTML. Clearing displayed output

Tags: javascript, html, output, return-value, reset

I have created a simple Cost Estimator in HTML Javascript. It does a simple calculation and displays the answer. I do not know how to reset the answer output when pressing the Reset button.

Here is codepen : http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/FgJAd

The reset button resets the form but I do not no how to reset answer. I know it because of how I have displayed the answer, but do not know the correct process to clear the output.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>Cost Estimator</h1>
 <form>
 <input type= "numbers" id="x" placeholder = "Length" /><br />
 <input type= "numbers" id="y" placeholder = "Width"/><br />
  <input type= "numbers" id="z" placeholder = "Height"/><br />

  <select id="choice" >
    <option value = "1">option 1</option>
    <option value = "2">0ption 2</option>
    <option value = "3">option 3</option>
</select>
   <br/>
   <br/>
<input id= "est" type="button" value = "Estimate" onclick= "calculator()"/>
<input id= "reset" type="reset" value = "Reset"/>
</form>
 <h1 id="result"> = </h1>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function calculator(){
    var x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
    var y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
    var z = Number(document.getElementById("z").value);
    var p = Number(30);
    var result;
 var calc = document.getElementById("choice").value
    switch(calc){
        case"1" : result = z * p; 
    break;
        case"2" : result = x * p + 50; 
    break;
        case"3" : result = x * p + 30; 
    break;       

}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " =  £  " + result;  
}
```

http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/FgJAd

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to your form's [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/reset) event:

```
// document.forms[0] assumes your form is the first in the DOM
document.forms[0].addEventListener('reset', function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
});
```